# disable adding new tags on the edit and add post

Tags: user-roles, tags, editor

I use the admin menu editor plugin.
I have not allowed editors and authors to access the tags section

But they can add a new tag in the post edit section
This is not good for our site

We want them to only use tags that have already been created

Is there a way to disable adding new tags on the edit and add post, by editors and authors?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A CSS rule would be the simple action.

You can just create a single global admin area foot script set of instructions and disable a whole series of elements by user capability and simply add instructions as needed, and affect all areas of the admin area.

**functions.php** or create a plugin that would give flexibility to be used on any WP site without dependence on specific theme.

```php
add_action('admin_print_footer_scripts', function() {
  ## block fields from non admins

// set default empty vars
  $non_admin_css_blocks= $non_admin_js_blocks='';

// user condition check
  if( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
    $non_admin_blocks = '
    #post_tag .jaxtag, 
    .other-field, 
    .another-field {display: none !important;}
    ';

    // javascript instructions
    $non_admin_js_blocks = '
      $("#post-body #title,#edit-slug-box button.edit-slug").attr("disabled","disabled");
    ';
  }

  $css = '
  <style>
  '.$non_admin_blocks.'
  </style>
  ';
  $js = '
  <script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    '.$non_admin_js_blocks.'
  });
  </script>
  ';

  echo $css . $js;
});
```

### Note

You can always scan the files in wp-admin to find all the hooks that will deliver any alteration desired. Just search for `do_action` or `apply_filters` and read the commented tip to determine firing time and behavior. If a hook has a variable, that will be used in the callback argument. If there are multiple vars you will need to define the count. EG

`priority 10,args count 2`

```php
add_action('do_something_different', function($alt,$target) {

}10,2);
```

Comment: I want this box to still be displayed and authors to be able to use previous tags with search
But they cannot create a new label
And use other tags
Our labels are currently around 6000 pieces

Comment: that's what the javascript line does. Do not use the CSS rule, just add the tag class to the comma separated array of the jQuery line. In fact just create an array of input field classes or ID which you just want to disable. `var field_disable = [
"#post-body #title",
"#edit-slug-box button.edit-slug",
"input#new-tag-post_tag",
"input.tagadd"
];`
`$.each(field_disable, function(i,v) {
$(v).attr("disabled","disabled");
});`