# disable the post title field after publishing

Tags: editor, publish

Changing the title of the article can be very dangerous for search

I'm looking for a way to disable the post title field after publishing for authors and editors

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: try css rule display:none for the title container ID titlediv along with a php condition when in post edit view `if( isset($_GET['post']) && isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'edit' && !current_user_can('manage_options') ) { 'css rule here' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks [nadal](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/200739/nadal)

i change to this code

```
add_action('edit_form_after_title', function($post) {
    if( !empty($post->post_title) && $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {
        echo '<style>#titlediv {visibility: hidden !important; height: 1px !important;}</style>';
        echo '<div id="titlewrap"><input type="text" name="post_title" size="30" value="'.$post->post_title.'" id="title-2" style="padding:3px 8px;font-size:1.7em;line-height:100%;height:1.7em;width:100%;outline:0;margin:0 0 3px;background-color:#fff;" disabled></div>';
        echo '<div id="edit-slug-box" class="hide-if-no-js"><strong>slug : </strong><a href="'.get_site_url().'/'.urldecode($post->post_name).'">'.get_site_url().'/'.urldecode($post->post_name).'</a></div>';
    }
});
```

Comment: you don't need to hide the container if you still want the text field visible but disabled. Better off using javascript to add the `disabled` attribute. `<script>jQuery(function($) { $("#title,button.edit-slug").attr("disabled","disabled") });</script>`

Answer (score 2):

Use the action hook `edit_form_after_title`

The `display:none` rule might cause some JS issue so it might be best to use `visibility:hidden` so the element is still accessible to whatever scripts in the DOM.

This condition will hide the form fields and show the title and URL statically.

```php
add_action('edit_form_after_title', function($post) {
    if( !empty($post->post_title) && !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
        echo '<style>#titlediv {visibility: hidden !important; height: 1px !important;}</style>';
        echo '<h2>'.$post->post_title.'</h2>';
        echo '<a href="'.get_site_url().'/'.$post->post_name.'">'.get_site_url().'/'.$post->post_name.'</a>';
    }
});
```

Note that post titles can also be edited within table list view with **quick edit** so you'll need to hook into that location also and do the same.

Since your concern is search engine 404 related, you might wanna consider disabling a lot more which could change the post's URL or accessibility:

- move to trash
- category change
- post privacy
- publish state
- publish date change

Also if yo use a third party visual composer like Elementor or similar, those may still allow title change and not use the ID used by WP core system.

#### Post object returned by var $post

**new post**

```
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] => 369
    [post_author] => 1
    [post_date] => 2023-09-22 18:19:21
    [post_date_gmt] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => 
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => auto-draft
    [comment_status] => closed
    [ping_status] => closed
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] => 
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 2023-09-22 18:19:21
    [post_modified_gmt] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 0
    [guid] => https://example.net/?page_id=369
    [menu_order] => 0
    [post_type] => page
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [filter] => raw
)
```

**saved post edit mode**

```
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] => 274
    [post_author] => 1
    [post_date] => 2023-09-11 03:55:29
    [post_date_gmt] => 2023-09-11 07:55:29
    [post_content] => there is always stuff to write
    [post_title] => The Page
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => publish
    [comment_status] => closed
    [ping_status] => closed
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] => the-page
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 2023-09-22 18:08:33
    [post_modified_gmt] => 2023-09-22 22:08:33
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 0
    [guid] => https://example.net/?page_id=274
    [menu_order] => 0
    [post_type] => page
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [filter] => edit
)
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to answer this question as well?

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/418888/disable-adding-new-tags-on-the-edit-and-add-post